# String Sorting Based on Last Character in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string, sorting

I want to sort my string array based on last character. Here is my string array:

```
["c_572A267C-DAC8-487D-B1AF-719FE8E3A6AB_FF6E00_2",
 "b_69E21DC6-431C-4373-B4F1-90BF7FB5462B_FFC000_1"]
```

Now I want to sort this array based on last value that is **after** **last underscore(_).**
Is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Is the last underscore always followed by a single digit? Or can it be multiple digits or other characters? If yes: how should they be sorted, numerically or as string? What if the suffices are equal?  – A precise problem statement, covering all possible cases, is always a good start.

Answer (score 2):

`sorted` can provide a custom sort condition for example (assuming that all strings are not empty)

```
let array = ["c_572A267C-DAC8-487D-B1AF-719FE8E3A6AB_FF6E00_2", "b_69E21DC6-431C-4373-B4F1-90BF7FB5462B_FFC000_1"]
let sortedArray = array.sorted { $0.substring(from: $0.index(before: $0.endIndex)) < $1.substring(from: $1.index(before: $1.endIndex)) }
```

Swift 3+ the syntax is much more convenient

```
let array = ["c_572A267C-DAC8-487D-B1AF-719FE8E3A6AB_FF6E00_2", "b_69E21DC6-431C-4373-B4F1-90BF7FB5462B_FFC000_1"]
let sortedArray = array.sorted { $0.suffix(1) < $1.suffix(1) }
```

Comment: May I mention that if the array contains an empty string (`""`) it will cause a crash: `fatal error: cannot decrement before startIndex`.

Comment: Yes, I know I added an assumption, but it seems that the OP wants to sort non-empty strings anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No doubt it is. By using [sorted(by:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296815-sorted), you could do it like this:

```
let myArray = ["c_572A267C-DAC8-487D-B1AF-719FE8E3A6AB_FF6E00_2",
               "b_69E21DC6-431C-4373-B4F1-90BF7FB5462B_FFC000_1"]

let sortedArray = myArray.sorted {
    guard let str1LastChar = $0.characters.last, let str2LastChar = $1.characters.last else {
        return false
    }

    return str1LastChar < str2LastChar
}

print(sortedArray)
```

Note that if `myArray` contains any empty string (`""`) the sort should be as is.

Comment: But (unless I am mistaken again), there is still a problem: With a="X", b="", c="Y": (a, b) are incomparable and (b, c) are incomparable. Then (a, c) must also be incomparable, but they are not. – A *symmetric* condition returning `false` always looks suspicious to me.

Comment: I think that your point is clear to me now, it is something similar to transitive property logic, right? the current output for sorting `["X", "", "Y"]` should be the same, with no edit...

Comment: It is called "transitivity of incomparability" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings and ensures that the elements are totally ordered by `<` (with "incomparable" elements being "equal") – Of course all this matters only if there *are* empty strings at all.

Comment: Ah yes, Martin's completely right; to make it formally valid, you would need to change it such that some order is established when `""` is compared with any other non-empty string. e.g having it sort less than any other non-empty strings: `switch ($0.characters.last, $1.characters.last) {case let (lhsLast?, rhsLast?): return lhsLast < rhsLast case (_, nil): return false case (nil, _): return true }`

Answer (score 0):

One more answer with `Higher Order Function`:

> 1. Reverse Each word in an `Array`
> 2. Then, Sort

```
let arr = ["c_572A267C-DAC8-487D-B1AF-719FE8E3A6AB_FF6E00_2",
               "b_69E21DC6-431C-4373-B4F1-90BF7FB5462B_FFC000_1"]
```

**One Line:**

```
let returnValue = arr.map({String($0.reversed())}).sorted().map({String($0.reversed())})
```

**Multi Line:**

```
let reverseEachWordsArr = arr.map { value in
    return String(value.reversed())
}

let finalCharSortArr = reverseEachWordsArr.sorted().map { word  in
    return String(word.reversed())
}
print(finalCharSortArr)
```

OUTPUT:

```
["b_69E21DC6-431C-4373-B4F1-90BF7FB5462B_FFC000_1", 
 "c_572A267C-DAC8-487D-B1AF-719FE8E3A6AB_FF6E00_2"]
```